# How to store time period in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to store efficiently a time period?

**First approach :**

---

```
{
   "workingDayStartAt: "9:00",
   "workingDayEndAt: "18:00"
}
```

---

**Second approach :**

---

```
{
   "workingDay": "9:00 - 18:00"
}
```

---

In the first approach I have an extra field in db.
In the second I have to parse "workingDay"(start, end) on the client side.

Comment: I would suggest to store both `workingDayStartAt` and `workingDayEndAt` as a `Date` object. Then it is easy to calculate the difference and it is future proof. It does not matter if you store as two fields (i.e. `workingDayStartAt` and `workingDayEndAt`) or an array (i.e. `workingDay: [Start-Date, End-Date]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider few things :

1. I would say not to store time period in the format of `String` cause querying can be challenging,
   Let's say when you've query documents with `workingDayStartAt` at
   `10:00 am` & `workingDayEndAt` at `12:00 pm` it wouldn't be possible
   with **Second** approach cause passing those values & matching against a
   string is not easy. So no to **Second**.
2. Since you're left over with **First** approach `{ "workingDayStartAt: "9:00", "workingDayEndAt: "18:00" }`. But I've few
   suggestions :

   a) Do not store numbers as string in database, Always store numbers as
   integers in MongoDB which helps you a lot while querying. An extra number field with index doesn't cost much compared to string comparison while querying (It can be an issue if your doc is too large/ too many indexes or collection size is too big - In general/most cases it's not an issue).

   b) Also you what if in future you've different time periods for different days in a week ? - So if that can happen you need to store day wise, You can have something like below :

**A field `timePeriods` :**

```
{
  timePeriods : { /** This can be an array of objects as well */
  "0": [{ workingDayStartAt:  900, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }], /** Instead of array it can be an object */
  "1": [{ workingDayStartAt: 1000, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }],
  "2": [{ workingDayStartAt: 1100, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }],
  "3": [{ workingDayStartAt: 1130, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }],
  "4": [{ workingDayStartAt:  930, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }],
  "5": [{ workingDayStartAt: 1000, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }],
  "6": [{ workingDayStartAt: 1200, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }],
  }
}

/** Just in case if you've two different start & end hours on same day */
"0": [{ workingDayStartAt: 0900, workingDayEndAt: 1100 }, { workingDayStartAt: 1300, workingDayEndAt: 1800 } ]

/** Or if you've same times everyday 
 * (You can just say `'0_7': {exists : true}` to check if all days have same times & check for docs with particular times)*/
 {
    timePeriods : {
         "0_7": [{ workingDayStartAt: 900, workingDayEndAt: 1800 }]
      }
  }
```